# Upload a img from Colab to a Google Drive folder

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, drive

This should be pretty straight forward but I have been searching for a few hours and I failed to achieve this.

I'm trying to save a simple matplotlib figure I generated in Google Colab to a Google Colab folder and then upload it to a folder in my Google Drive.

I have looked into the doc here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#simple

And many other answers similar to this one: 
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14186/use-pydrive-to-upload-files-to-google-drive-folder/26644#26644

And couldn't accomplish it.

Can someone provide a full example of this working?

Comment: Have you tried mounting the Google drive to your Colab notebook? ```from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')

Comment: [This link](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb) details multiple ways to connect your notebook to your google drive. You can mount your drive, use the pyDrive wrapper, or the REST API yourself